# iterate over all boolean combinations

Tags: c++, testing

in a function I want to test I have ~10 booleans, that changes the result of my function by a series of if-else, etc.
I'd like to run all the possible combinations automatically. I think of doing a std::vector, each element pointing to one of my 10 booleans.
Now is there a generic algorithm to iterate through all combinations of bool values in my vector?

thanks

Comment: do yourself a favour: Write separate tests....

Comment: A function with ten boolean parameters and a bunch of if-else? Are you sure you can't refactor that with a cleaner design (like [having separate functions for the different cases](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceParameterWithExplicitMethods.html), for instance)?

Comment: I think I only have 5 bool actually. Basically this is a function that append different pieces of SQL query to another SQL query and I want to test that for all combination the query is correct (its syntax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really user friendly, posting this just for fun:

```
bool b[10];
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 1024 ; i++ )
{
   for ( int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++ )
   {
      b[j] = i & (1 << j);
   }
   testFunction (b[0],....,b[9]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your function has a signature like

```
void f( bool b0, bool b1, bool b2 ... bool b9 );
```

you could exploit binary arithmetic:

```
void f( bool b0, bool b1, bool b2, bool b3, bool b4,
        bool b5, bool b6, bool b7, bool b8, bool b9 );

int main()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < (1 << 10); ++i ) {
        f( i & 0x001, i & 0x002, i & 0x004, i & 0x008, i & 0x010,
           i & 0x020, i & 0x040, i & 0x080, i & 0x100, i & 0x200 );
    }
}
```

This will call `f` 1024 times, each time with a different combination of booleans.

Comment: Same principle, much more user-friendly :) +1

Comment: @Frerich we are using the function but not saving the results , any way to save the result too ?

Comment: @user2754673 I don't understand the question; the function I sketched produces no results.

Comment: yes. You are not you are just iterating all possible truth table structure. How to generate results too is my question.

Comment: @user2754673 Well you would generate results by defining `f` appropriately. You could collect the return values of `f` in a data structure, e.g. a `std::vector`. Your question is too generic to really say something specific.

Answer (score 3):

You can construct [`bitset<10>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/) from each of the 2^10 combinations:

```
for (int mask = 0 ; mask != (1<<10) ; mask++) {
    bitset<10> bits(mask);
    // At this point, bits[i] contains true of false
    // for the combination of bits in mask.
}
```

Comment: +1 for thinking of `std::bitset`, saves you from having to test the bits using binary operators.